# Is there anyway to force program to use page file virtual memory when run out of RAM in .net?

Tags: .net, out-of-memory

```
struct SomeStruct
{
   //some fields, store ~3kb
}

List<SomeStruct> lst = new List<SomeStruct>();

for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
   lst.Add(new SomeStruct(/*...*/)); //somewhere we get OutOfMemory exception
```

So... I want it to use virtual memory and continue working, instead of exception

Comment: You're already using virtual memory, but you ran out of contiguous address space.  Also, .Net objects cannot be bigger than 2GB.

Comment: And what leads you to believe it is not using virtual memory?

Comment: If you're going to have an enormous data structure of known size, you may as well pass the size into the `List` constructor.

Comment: ehm, it ran out of memory too fast and my laptop has too few of RAM. I get exception when around 149k objects has been added, i though it extremely small amount if count virtual memory, but normal if count only RAM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that.  The idea behind virtual memory is that programs *can't tell the difference*.  If you are getting an OutOfMemory exception, it means the OS has told you "you can't get anymore", including virtual memory.

If anything, you would need to fiddle with settings in the OS and how it handles virtual memory.